# Compute returns from data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how do I compute the returns for the following dataframe? Let the name of the dataframe be `refined_df`

```
               0       1     
Date                
2020-02-03  TSLA    MSFT    
2020-02-19  AMZN    ADBE    
2020-03-05  OYST    GPRO    
2020-03-20  AMZN    OYST    
2020-04-06  SGEN    AEYE    
2020-04-22  AEYE    TSLA    
2020-05-07  AAPL    SGEN
```

and we also have another dataframe, `storage_openprices`

```
                  AAL        AAPL         ADBE      AEYE           AMZN        GOOG  GPRO         MSFT   OYST   PACB    RADI    SGEN    TSLA
Date                                                    
2020-01-14  27.910000   79.175003   347.010010  5.300000    1885.880005 1439.010010 4.230   163.389999  28.010000   4.850000    NaN 104.849998  108.851997
2020-01-15  27.450001   77.962502   346.420013  5.020000    1872.250000 1430.209961 4.160   162.619995  26.510000   4.800000    NaN 108.550003  105.952003
2020-01-16  27.790001   78.397499   345.980011  5.060000    1882.989990 1447.439941 4.280   164.350006  25.530001   4.930000    NaN 107.330002  98.750000
2020-01-17  28.299999   79.067497   349.000000  4.840000    1885.890015 1462.910034 4.360   167.419998  24.740000   5.030000    NaN 108.410004  101.522003
2020-01-21  27.969999   79.297501   346.369995  4.880000    1865.000000 1479.119995 4.280   166.679993  26.190001   4.950000    NaN 108.379997  106.050003
```

What I want is to return a new dataframe with the log returns of particular stock for the specific duration.

For example, the (0,0) entry of the returned dataframe is the log return for holding TSLA from 2020-02-03 till 2020-02-19. We refer to the open prices for tesla from `refined_df`

Similarly, for the (1,0) entry we return the log return for holding AMZN from 2020-02-19 till 2020-03-05.

Unsure if I should be using the `apply`   and lambda function. My issue is calling the next row in computing the log returns.

EDIT:
The output, a dataframe should look like

```
               0       1     
Date                
2020-02-03  0.14    0.21    
2020-02-19  0.18    0.19    
2020-03-05  XXXX    XXXX    
2020-03-20  XXXX    XXXX    
2020-04-06  XXXX    XXXX    
2020-04-22  XXXX    XXXX    
2020-05-07  XXXX    XXXX
```

where 0.14 (a made-up number) is the log return of TSLA from 2020-02-03 to 2020-02-19, i.e. log(TSLA open price on 2020-02-19) - log(TSLA open price on 2020-02-03)

Thanks!

Comment: How the logs should be packed? could you give an example of the output?

Comment: Is it many dataframes for each element of refined_df? In your example 12 items (because closing data for the last one is uncknown. btw are you sure that closing for TSLA is 2020-02-19 and not 2020-04-22?

Comment: Please take a look at the edition

Comment: Personally for me, it is even less clear now)

Comment: Maybe create a small available sample dataset, and give a desired output on the sample will be more useful. As we may confuse with the `log` which you defined. Does the "log" mean `openprices` in  `storage_openprices`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) and `direction='forward'` parameter with reshaped both DataFrames by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print (refined_df)
               0     1
Date                  
2020-02-03  TSLA  MSFT
2020-02-19  AMZN  ADBE
2020-03-05  OYST  GPRO
2020-03-20  AMZN  OYST
2020-04-06  SGEN  AEYE
2020-04-22  AEYE  TSLA
2020-05-07  AAPL  SGEN

#changed datetiems for match
print (storage_openprices)
               AAL       AAPL        ADBE  AEYE         AMZN         GOOG  \
Date                                                                           
2020-02-14  27.910000  79.175003  347.010010  5.30  1885.880005  1439.010010   
2020-02-15  27.450001  77.962502  346.420013  5.02  1872.250000  1430.209961   
2020-02-16  27.790001  78.397499  345.980011  5.06  1882.989990  1447.439941   
2020-02-17  28.299999  79.067497  349.000000  4.84  1885.890015  1462.910034   
2020-02-21  27.969999  79.297501  346.369995  4.88  1865.000000  1479.119995   

            GPRO        MSFT       OYST  PACB  RADI        SGEN        TSLA  
Date                                                                         
2020-02-14  4.23  163.389999  28.010000  4.85   NaN  104.849998  108.851997  
2020-02-15  4.16  162.619995  26.510000  4.80   NaN  108.550003  105.952003  
2020-02-16  4.28  164.350006  25.530001  4.93   NaN  107.330002   98.750000  
2020-02-17  4.36  167.419998  24.740000  5.03   NaN  108.410004  101.522003  
2020-02-21  4.28  166.679993  26.190001  4.95   NaN  108.379997  106.050003
```

---

```
df1 = storage_openprices.stack().rename_axis(['Date','type']).reset_index(name='new')
df2 = refined_df.stack().rename_axis(['Date','cols']).reset_index(name='type')


new = (pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='Date',by='type', direction='forward')
         .pivot('Date','cols','new'))
print (new)
cols                  0           1
Date                               
2020-02-03   108.851997  163.389999
2020-02-19  1865.000000  346.369995
2020-03-05          NaN         NaN
2020-03-20          NaN         NaN
2020-04-06          NaN         NaN
2020-04-22          NaN         NaN
2020-05-07          NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Uhh I don't think this is what I want. Could you explain your method?

Comment: @finmathstudent - Answer was edited again.